# Сохранить одну таблицу при перезаписи базы данных

Tags: android, sqlite

В одном из своих приложений использую библиотеку `Android SQLiteAssetHelper` 
[вот эту](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)
И есть один вопрос при обновлении. В мануале указаны в основном миграции с изменениями схем [вот такие](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/blob/master/samples/database-v2-upgrade/src/main/assets/databases/northwind.db_upgrade_1-2.sql). Но в моем случае в базе при обновлении обычно меняется информация (расписание), появляются новые таблицы.И мне этот способ не совсем подходит. Потому что одна таблица - вкладка "избранное" - не меняется никогда. 
И , соответственно при обновлении, эти данные всегда теряются.

Собственно вопрос как в моем случае обновлять базу так, что бы одна таблица оставалась и не затиралась по дефолту.

В конструкторе делаю так:

```
public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
        try {
            myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            try {
                clearDB();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                setForcedUpgrade();
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "MyDatabase: " + e);
        }
    }
```

Ну и по мануалу вроде как база данных просто перезаписывается

```
 public void clearDB() {
    if (myDataBase != null && myDataBase.isOpen()) {
        myDataBase.close();
    }
    File file = new File(context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath());
    SQLiteDatabase.deleteDatabase(file);
}
```

А если нет, то вызывается метод библиотеки `getWritableDatabase()` который удаляет старую базу и записывает новую.

==UPD
Создаю скрипт для сохранения такого рода

```
ALTER TABLE "station_favorites" RENAME TO 'station_favorites_ME_TMP';
CREATE TABLE "station_favorites"
 (
 "_id"  int NOT NULL,
    "name"  TEXT,
    "to_station"    TEXT,
    "station_id"    TEXT
PRIMARY KEY ("_id")

);
INSERT INTO "station_favorites"  ("_id", "name", "to_station", "station_id" )
SELECT
    "_id",
    "name",
    "to_station",
    "station_id"

    FROM "station_favorites_ME_TMP";
DROP TABLE "station_favorites_ME_TMP";
```

При этом создаю так :

```
public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;}
```

Отваливается с ошибкой:

```
 (1) near "(": syntax error
```

2020-01-09 14:01:15.551 14385-14385/com.package
E/SQLiteAssetHelper: Couldn't open app_database_1.db for writing (will try read-only):
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE "station_favorites" (
    "_id"   int NOT NULL,
        "name"  TEXT,
        "to_station"    TEXT,
        "station_id"    TEXT
    PRIMARY KEY ("_id")

```
)
```

Comment: а зачем вы удаляете всю БД? не проще нужные данные только удалить/обновить? Тоже самое касается и колонок в таблице, добавляются они одним запросом `alter table my_table add column`. Ну и не хватает в вопросе что конкретно вы удаляете/обновляете, и структуры БД.

Comment: Допустим, иногда мне нужно добавить новую таблицу в базу в которой 100+ строк список предметов. В этом случае я делаю все на компе, потом просто кладду ее в ассеты и поднимаю версию. База перезаписывается. Избранные удаляются. Как делать что бы не удалялись?

Answer (score 0):

Эта библиотека очень упрощает работу с БД и первое, что вам нужно сделать, создать класс для открытия вашего файла БД:

```
public class DBAssetHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String DBName = "Имя базы данных";
private static final int DBVersion = 1;

public DBAssetHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBName, null, DBVersion);

    setForcedUpgrade(DBVersion); // При каждой замене файла БД на новый нужно просто увеличить значение DBVersion на 1

    }
}
```

Затем в коде получаете доступ к данным в БД:

```
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...

DBAssetHelper dbAssetHelper = new DBAssetHelper(this);
sqLiteDatabase = dbAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(); // База данных открыта, теперь вы можете оперировать ею

// Обращаетесь к базе данных и извлекаете из нее данные
try {
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query("Table",
                new String[]{"Title", "Name", "Description"},
                null, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            strTitle = cursor.getString(0);
            strName = cursor.getString(1);
            strDesription = cursor.getString(2);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "База данных недоступна " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Следовательно, когда вы обновляете файл базы данных, и, например, добавляете новый столбец просто в коде добавляете переменную с его именем, например: `Title, Name, SubName, Description`

Если добавляете таблицу, то создаете другой поток для работы с этой таблицей.

Таким образом, при каждой замене файла базы данных и увеличения значения переменной версии БД, в ней будут обновляться все данные, которые вы обновили и оставаться на месте все те данные, которые вы не затронули, в вашем случае колонка с избранным.

Comment: Там два конструктора, одиному из них не нужны аргументы, просто достаточно увеличить версию и все работает.

Comment: Вы попробовали передать переменную и ответили, или? И можете добавить в вопрос ссылку на библиотеку, которую используете для работы с БД?

Comment: ссылка есть в вопросе https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: Я использую эту же библиотеку и передаю в метод `setForcedUpgrade()` переменную с номером версии БД и все нормально работает.

Comment: Оно и так и так работает нормально. Можете показать как вы сохраняете пользовательские таблицы?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103080/discussion-between-mcdaggen-and-).

Comment: Ответил вам в чате